# Starter Kit for Arduino Cookbook

Tags: arduino-uno

I have this book here about Arduino. What kind of Kit should I purchase to get started? Would [this](https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B014L11IN6/ref=s9_wsim_gw_g147_i4_r?pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=8Z4628HN1J4H6NG4KKHX&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=6127e987-ce6a-47ca-bd15-51701a16b93c&pf_rd_i=desktop) work?

---

I'm not yet sure about what I'd like to do with Arduino, so I may prefer a pretty ***Universal Kit*** in order to cover a pretty wide range of projects.

Except this, I won't need any advanced stuff, at the moment, as a beginner I may want to understand the fundamentals, so will surely need **LEDs**, maybe **screens**, and other **basic** stuff like that.

Later on I may try to go for Wireless modules, but not at the moment as a beginner.

Any ideas? Hope to have clarified more or less what projects I'm aiming to, yeah the range is wide, but restricted to basic beginner projects.

Comment: *I'm not yet sure about what I'd like to do with Arduino* - Arduinos are a lot of fun, and you can learn a lot from them. However asking for a suitable kit for "I don't know what" is a big ask. I suggest a minimal kit (or just a plain Arduino) and do some of the tutorials. I think this question should be closed as too broad, but I'll leave it to my fellow community members to make that decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage to a kit is it includes a lot of stuff. You'll have a big selection of sensors and parts to choose from.

The disadvantage to a kit is it includes a lot of stuff. You'll have bought and paid for a big selection of sensors and parts, some of which you may never use.

Since you linked to Amazon, I assume you are someplace where shopping on line is convenient. In that case I'd start with a small handful parts and let your developing skills and interests guide your future purchases.

A bag of LEDs with resistors included is really basic - start there. I make up a dozen or so of them with a resistor permanently soldered to the cathode (ground) side of the LED (it doesn't matter which side you choose, just be consistent for your own sanity later on!) These are quicker to wire up on a breadboard than using separate LEDs and resistors, and they make a quick and dirty logic-probe ("Is there 5v on this board?", "Is this pin HIGH or LOW?") or output device.

A handful of push-buttons, often called "Tact switches", a few analog thermo sensors (LM34 or LM35 f/ex), and a light sensor, would start you off inexpensively while providing you opportunities to learn how connect these devices, some basic electronic theory, and some programming skills.

By then, you'll have a much better idea what kinds of projects you want to pursue and the parts necessary to build them.

Comment: Yeah guess you're right! Bought a very basic kit without an LCD and other stuff, this way I'll save some money and get a separate LCD for just 3€ instead of spending 20€ more for another kit which includes an LCD screen but even lots of other stuff I'm not sure I'll use it, at least at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange format is not well suited for opinions.  That said, people are apparently giving the kit good reviews.  And I see hardware that appears to allow for several projects (LED arrays?, motors?, ultrasonic-distance-measurement?, IR-remote-control?, Alpha-numeric-LCD?, 7-segmet-LED-display?, ect).  Which is more than you need for basic Arduino projects.

In general, it would make the most sense to find a kit with a book rather than obtain a book and a kit separately. This is because slight differences between the written material and independently obtained hardware will cause confusion.  This is generally not a problem for experienced embedded developers.

Keep in mind that embedded processor projects are half hardware and half software.  Since the hardware has already been collected, the majority of activity will be in software.  If this paradigm agrees with you, good luck & have fun.

Comment: Mmm you have a Kit to suggest?

Comment: The end goal for Stack Exchange is to have a list of clear questions with concise answers that can be searched through.  Opinions do not fit into that paradigm. But, no, I have no specific kit to suggest.  Only, for a beginner, to find a kit with a book so it is clear how to proceed.  While there are many standards for electronic parts, there are also many variations.  It sometimes only takes 1 or 2 variations to make a part unusable to the beginner.  That is why I am suggesting  to buy a kit and book together.

Comment: I'll add this...  I did not see a servo motor in that kit.   Servo motors are more expensive because they contain a computer-to-motor interface inside.  Most beginning Arduino uses find servo motors fun to work with.  And they are easy to interface (both hardware and software) to an Arduino.  You can easily pick up servo motors that work with Arduinos independently of buying an Arduno kit.